# Check if null before set to null?

Tags: c#, .net, null

Should we check if variable is null before setting it to null?

```
if (MyBills != null) 
{
    MyBills = null;
}
```

For, example, in a [Java related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583454/check-if-variable-null-before-assign-to-null) the performance implications are minimal. 
Is this the case in C#? Other implications?

### Testing

I've created the following code to test:

```
var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

int iterations = int.MaxValue;
List<int> myBills= null;
for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
{
    if (myBills!= null)
    {
        myBills = null;
    }
}
watch.Stop();
var elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
Console.WriteLine(elapsedMs);
```

Running it on [rextester](http://rextester.com/) with and without the `if (myList != null)` the results are as following:

```
With check      Without check
988             941
938             1021
953             987
998             973
1004            1031

Average 
976.2           990.6
```

So, even testing it in a non-controlled environment, the performance implications are irrelevant.

Comment: Of course No, for what?

Comment: What you call *variable* could be a property with setter, which code you don't want to run, then you do exactly this.

Comment: _"Should we check..."_ Only if you want to handle that case, f.e. log it

Comment: @MegaTron, exactly. That's the question.
I would appreciate downvoters comments.

Comment: @MarioLevrero As the timings are kind of an answer you should remove them from the question and self answer.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder I did the tests to improved the question, based on downvotes, before I saw your tests.

Comment: @MarioLevrero I edited my answer with my tests after you did yours so that's fine! And I suppose on that basis might be worth keeping it in.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, there is not much use. Probably checking the *variable* being null or not is just as expensive as setting it to null one time too many.

If it was a *property*, with additional logic behind it, it could make sense to test it before, but that should actually be the responsibility of the logic in the property, not your code.

Comment: Thanks, Patrick. I don't get why so many downvoters for the question.

Comment: Maybe they'd expected a little more effort in asking, like now you linked to Java as comparison. You could also have ran some tests.

Comment: Patrick, I've updated the question with some tests as you suggested. I think that only with constructive critics as you did we can make a better S.O. Thanks again

Comment: You are welcome. Indeed, it doesn't care too much as you see in the test. although there are better testing methods, which will yield a more accurate result.

Answer (score 5):

Aside from the property/setter argument I can't see any logical reason for this in the code you have provided.

However, if you want to perform extra operations on the object before setting it to null it makes sense:

```
if (MyBills != null)
{
     MyBills.Dispose();
     MyBills = null;
}
```

Or perform some other operation like logging a result.

But these two examples are both outside of the example code you have provided.

---

Because people seem to be questioning the use case for my first example, here's one. This will prevent multiple calls to `Dispose` causing an `ObjectDisposedException`.

```
public class MyClass : IDisposable
{
    private SomeDisposableObject _disposableObject;

    //Some code

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_disposableObject != null)
        {
            _disposableObject.Dispose();
            _disposableObject = null;
        }
    }
}
```

---

I have performed some timings and found the following results:

> valueClass with null check = 1361
>   nullClass with null check = 1173
>   valueClass with no null check = 1208
>   nullClass with no null check = 1148

As you can see without the null check it is slightly quicker but not enough for any significant optimisation. Also I performed these timings from the compiler in debug mode with optimisations turned off so they are not 100% accurate/relevant.

However, when I ran in release mode, with optimisations enabled outside of the compiler the results were so close together it was even more negligible to check or not.

And the test code:

```
using System;

namespace NullCheckTest
{
    class Program
    {
        const int iterations = 10000000;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyClass valueClass = new MyClass() { Value = 10 };
            MyClass nullClass = null;

            Console.WriteLine($"valueClass with null check = {TestNullCheck(valueClass)}");
            Console.WriteLine($"nullClass with null check = {TestNullCheck(nullClass)}");

            Console.WriteLine($"valueClass with no null check = {TestNoNullCheck(valueClass)}");
            Console.WriteLine($"nullClass with no null check = {TestNoNullCheck(nullClass)}");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static long TestNullCheck(MyClass myClass)
        {
            MyClass initial = myClass;

            System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
            for (int i = 0; i < iterations; ++i)
            {
                sw.Start();

                if (myClass != null)
                {
                    myClass = null;
                }

                sw.Stop();

                myClass = initial;
            }

            return sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        }

        static long TestNoNullCheck(MyClass myClass)
        {
            MyClass initial = myClass;

            System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
            for (int i = 0; i < iterations; ++i)
            {
                sw.Start();

                myClass = null;

                sw.Stop();

                myClass = initial;
            }

            return sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        }
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you are modifing a code of OP by adding something inside. That is not really an answer to his question.

Comment: @Sinatr Which is what my ending statement states. However, it is still an answer because it states a use case for this.

Comment: And there are not that much cases for calling `Dispose` by hand. `using` is much more useful for this.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Except in a disposable class with a field that needs disposing. That is a common use case for this in my opinion.

Comment: If a class supports `IDisposable`, I will wrap it by `using` block when calling. No need to set to null. Also, if it is an instance of a class, just creates new instance again. Like `var mc = new MyClass();`

Comment: Note: You all seem to be getting to caught up in my provided example, it was just to show a use case for this i.e. perform some operations on the object.

Answer (score -2):

To answer the question: No, there is no need.

However. As a general rule of thumb object variables and properties should never be null, as it forces you to always have to check the code if the value is being set somewhere.

What you're supposed to do, is use a custom class [`Maybe<>`](http://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2015/03/13/functional-c-non-nullable-reference-types/) to indicate that an object variable or property might not be initialized.

Like so:

```
public class Maybe<T> where T : class
{
    public readonly T Value { get; }

    public Maybe(T value)
    {
        _Value = value;
    }

    public bool HasValue => _Value != null;
    public bool HasNoValue => _Value == null;

    public static operation Maybe<T>(T value) => new Maybe(value);
}
```

Then you can use it thus:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Maybe<Bar> Bar { get; set; }
    public int GetBarCount()
    {
        return Bar.HasValue ? Bar.Count : 0;
    }
}

public class Bar
{
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

The above code will work in all of the following examples:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.Bar = new Bar(); // Outputs 0 when GetBarCount is called
foo.Bar = new Bar { Count = 2 }; // Outputs 2 when GetBarCount is called
foo.Bar = new Maybe<Bar>(new Bar()); // Outputs 0 when GetBarCount is called
foo.Bar = new Maybe<Bar>(new Bar { Count = 2 }); // Outputs 2 when GetBarCount is called
foo.Bar = new Maybe<Bar>(null); // Outputs 0 when GetBarCount is called
foo.Bar = null;  // Outputs 0 when GetBarCount is called
```

Note! - When using `Maybe<Bar>` you explicitly mark `Foo.Bar` as not always having a value, and provides a strong signal of it. Not marking it with `Maybe<Bar>`, however, signals that it will always have a value. By using the `Maybe<>` wrapper in the right places, the code becomes much easier to work with, as you no longer have to do *null* checks for unwrapped object variables and properties.

Comment: Why obfuscate code like this? Also you are still checking for null, this wrapper class is confusing and pointless in my opinion.

Comment: See the note I added at the bottom. It should explain it well enough.

Comment: I understand the why you've done it, I just don't see the point for it.

Comment: I first read it here, and have been using it ever since. It has helped improve the readability and useability of the code we write at work. It is of course up to the individual developer to use it or not. We've had great success with it, and so others might as well.

http://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2015/03/13/functional-c-non-nullable-reference-types/

Comment: What is the use of `return Bar.HasValue ? Bar.Count : 0;` over `return Bar?.Count ?? 0;`? This is creating massive overhead with no gain at all.

Comment: The use lies in it being explicit that `Bar` might not have a value. To avoid your software crashing with a `NullReferenceException` when accessing `Bar.Count` when the instance of `Bar` is `null`, you will, without the `Maybe<Bar>` wrapper, have to check the implementation of whatever code produced the value for `Bar`.

Check the link I posted in the comment above this. It provides far more detail on the subject.

Comment: Yuck. Yuck, yuck, yuck.